# OpenX --- javascript in banners

Tags: openx, adbannerview, advertisement-server

Does OpenX allow to create banners that contain executable javascript code?
I need Javascript in banner, to process clicks (an another events) on some banner elements.

I'am going to use type of banner invocation --- Javascript Tag

Answer (score 0):

You can  choose the type of the banner as "OpenX Generic HTML Banner"

Then  write your executable java script codes

Regards,

Chinnu.G

Answer (score 0):

You can also prepend/append any kind of code (html/css/js) through zone and banner settings (advanced tab). I've used this to attach custom google analytics event tracking depending on the zone and banner combination... works like a charm